# Is there a reason why the local strategy for sails-generate-auth does not set req.session.authenticated to true

Tags: sails.js

When I login using the local strategy subsequent requests having the `sessionAuth` policy on them fail because `req.session.authenticated` is undefined. I've excerpted a portion of the `login` function from `api/services/protocols/local.js`. I've inserted a comment for the code I believe is missing.

```
    passport.validatePassword(password, function (err, res) {
      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      }

      if (!res) {
        req.flash('error', 'Error.Passport.Password.Wrong');
        return next(null, false);
      } else {

        ///// Shouldn't authenticated get set true here?
        ///// req.session.authenticated = true;

        return next(null, user);
      }
    });
```

Comment: I think a new tag sails-generate-x might be useful to distinguish questions about custom sails generators from generic sailsjs questions. Perhaps somebody with enough rep could add it?

Comment: Use req.isAuthenticated() for check if user is authenticated and change it in sessionAuth policy

Comment: @AlbertoSouza My question is really more about why isn't it there already. Seems like the local strategy simply won't work without it yet people seem to be using it successfully. I guess I should open this as an issue in GitHub instead

Comment: @Melvin its any HTTP request that requires the user to be authenticated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by Alberto Souza the local strategy works if you change `sessionAuth.js` from:

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.session.authenticated) {
    return next();
  }

  return res.forbidden('You are not permitted to perform this action.');
};
```

to:

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    return next();
  }

  return res.forbidden('You are not permitted to perform this action.');
};
```

So the answer to my question seems to be `sessionAuth.js` is part of the default sails app generation and not created  when you run `sails generate auth` and therefore is a change you need to make manually that the documentation neglects to tell you about.